# why when i choose another file and submit, another request with the old file is sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-upload-file-plugin

Hi i'm using [Jquery Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). I've got this problem:

when i upload the first file this work fine,a single request is sent.

But if i select a second file and i upload it,two request are sent and not one how i expected, the first with the old file and the second with the new one. 
how i can avoid this behavior?

here's the code:

html:

```
<form id="upload"   >
Select video to upload:
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="upl" data-url="php/fileUploader/uploaderVideoHandler.php" >
<input type="submit" value="Upload " name="submit">
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
   method:'POST',
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4)$/i,
    dataType: 'json',
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    replaceFileInput:false,
    autoUpload:false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('#upload').submit(

            function (e) {  
                            e.preventDefault();

                            data.submit();
            });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        data.file
        $('#progress .bar').text('Upload finished.');
    },
       progressall: function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
      );
    }
  });
 });
```

i try to reset data.files with

```
data.files.pop();
```

but doesn't work.

**Solved:**
Instead using

```
 <input type="submit" value="Upload " name="submit">
```

i used a button

```
 <button id="up_btn">upload</button>
```

and i've changed add function to:

```
    $("#up_btn").off('click').on('click', function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        data.submit();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: did you try with : replaceFileInput:true, ???

Comment: i also try to add in done data.files.pop() but  this error occur Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

Comment: completely remove this block : add: function (e, data) {  }   and try

Comment: i try but i want that my file are uploaded when upload button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending few hour on `Jquery File Upload` 
I came to know that you can upload file in this way in order to have syn file upload 
you can check the documentation [here](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html)

**Problem found**

```
While doing data.submit() in add fileupload you are actually re-submiting
the form again n again therefore more than 1 ajax occurs.
```

**Solution**

**HTML**

```
Select video to upload:
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    var url = 'server/php/',
    uploadButton = $('<button/>')
    .prop('disabled', true)
    .on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data();
        $this
        .off('click')
        .on('click', function () {
            $this.remove();
            data.abort();
        });
        data.submit().always(function () {
            $this.remove();
        });
    });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        replaceFileInput:false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 999000,
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')

            if (!index) {
                node.append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.error) {
            node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    })
});
```

**Final Code will be :-**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload.css">

Select video to upload:
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<div id="files" class="files"></div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    var url = 'server/php/',
    uploadButton = $('<button/>')
    .prop('disabled', true)
    .on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data();
        $this
        .off('click')
        .on('click', function () {
            $this.remove();
            data.abort();
        });
        data.submit().always(function () {
            $this.remove();
        });
    });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        replaceFileInput:false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 999000,
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')

            if (!index) {
                node.append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.error) {
            node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    })
});
</script>
```